# SQL Refund Calculation Wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was running a query to check datausage for one company
and stumbled upon a problem, I have noticed that KB usage in final state is more than it should be. Refund script is working wrong.

I have diagnosed the problem and noticed that:
In spare 1 (refund) there is values that are not "-800" sometimes there is values that are > 0 which is a problem since refund should be minus always.

How can I implement that? I have written this but I have no idea how to continue:

```
SELECT callclass,redirectingnumber,spare1,spare2
  FROM [CDR_Week_43].[dbo].[CDR-2013-10-20]
where 1=1
and mvno_id = 7
and callclass = 29
if [spare1] = 'Refund' and [spare2] > 0
then
```

In spare1 we will get 'refund' string and in spare2 there will be the value.
What I want to do is if the value is greater than 0, for example 300 it will be shown as -300 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This query always return `spare2` less than 0:

```
SELECT callclass,redirectingnumber,spare1,
       case when spare2 > 0 then spare2 * -1 else spare2 end as spare2
FROM [CDR_Week_43].[dbo].[CDR-2013-10-20]
where mvno_id = 7 and callclass = 29
```

using `case` statement you can manipulate value in the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CALLCLASS
    , REDIRECTINGNUMBER
    , SPARE1
    , CASE SPARE2 > 0 THEN SPARE2*-1 ELSE SPARE2 END AS SPARE2
FROM
    [CDR_Week_43].[dbo].[CDR-2013-10-20]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND mvno_id = 7
    AND callclass = 29
```

Answer (score 0):

To offer another option - use the [`Abs()` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

> A mathematical function that returns the absolute (positive) value of the specified numeric expression.

```
SELECT ...
     , Abs(spare2) * -1 As spare2
       ...
```